# Using ddply inside a function

Tags: r, plyr

I'm trying to make a function using ddply inside of it. However I can't get to work. This is a dummy example reproducing what I get. Does this have anything to do [this bug](https://github.com/hadley/plyr/issues/3)?

```
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)

foo <- function(data, fac1, fac2, bar) {
  res <- ddply(data, .(fac1, fac2), mean(bar))
  res
}

foo(diamonds, "color", "cut", "price")
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't believe this is a bug. `ddply` expects the name of a function, which you haven't really supplied with `mean(bar)`. You need to write a complete function that calculates the mean you'd like:

```
foo <- function(data, fac1, fac2, bar) {
  res <- ddply(data, c(fac1, fac2), function(x,ind){
                                     mean(x[,ind]},bar)
  res
}
```

Also, you shouldn't pass strings to `.()`, so I changed that to `c()`, so that you can pass the function arguments directly to `ddply`.

Comment: Your last sentence is the crucial hint. I was fiddling around with `as.name` etc. for a while.

Comment: @joran - Is there an easy way to pass a vector through var so that you can see summary statistics for several variables?

Comment: @dchandler I don't know what you mean. What is `var`?

Comment: @joran, I meant to write bar, not var. Basically, I'd be interested in having several columns where each shows a mean.

Comment: @dchandler Maybe `sapply(x[,ind],mean)` instead?

Comment: @joran -- Awesome, sapply that works great for showing multiple columns! One final question, what would be a syntax for showing two or more functions with that same vector?

Answer (score 10):

There are quite a few things wrong with your code, but the main issue is: you are passing column names as character strings.

Just doing a 'find-and-replace' with your parameters within the function yields:

```
res <- ddply(diamonds, .("color", "cut"), mean("price"))
```

If you understand how `ddply` works (I kind of doubt this, given the rest of the code), you will understand that this is not supposed to work: ignoring the error in the last part (the function), this should be (notice the lack of quotes: the .() notation is nothing more than plyr's way of providing the quotes):

```
res <- ddply(diamonds, .(color, cut), mean(price))
```

Fortunately, `ddply`also supports passing its second argument as a vector of characters, i.e. the names of the columns, so (once again disregarding issues with the last parameter), this should become:

```
foo <- function(data, facs, bar) {
  res <- ddply(data, facs, mean(bar))
  res
}

foo(diamonds, c("color", "cut"), "price")
```

Finally: the function you pass to `ddply` should be a function that takes as its first argument a data.frame, which will each time hold the part of you passed along data.frame (diamonds) for the current values of `color` and `cut`. `mean("price")` or `mean(price)` are neither. If you insist on using `ddply`, here's what you need to do:

```
foo <- function(data, facs, bar) {
  res <- ddply(data, facs, function(dfr, colnm){mean(dfr[,colnm])}, bar)
  res
}
foo(diamonds, c("color", "cut"), "price")
```

Comment: I see now what wrong with my code. No need to come hard on me though. Thanks!

Comment: @lselzer: I didn't mean to. I certainly do not think you made 'stupid mistakes' or anything. This rather popular error stems from the fact that R often makes it look like you can pass unquoted column names around (e.g. when defining formulas). It's wonderful when it works, but lures lots of people into false beliefs.

Comment: No problem, however the unnamed fucntion method doesn't work with summarise. Should I ask another question or update this one? As the bug I linked it's still unsolved (at least with plyr 1.5.1), I probably just melt the data.frame...

Comment: @lselzer: It will probably be more clear if you ask a new question (since this one's been marked answered, it won't generate too much attention anymore either, I guess)