# ddply arguments within function

Tags: r, plyr, igraph

I would like to use ddply within a function and pass the arguments to the outer function.

therefore I would need to be able to do something like this

```
ddply_wrapper <- function(x,byCol,cols){
    return(ddply(x,.(byCol),freq=length(x),cols))
}

library(ggplot2)
ddply_wrapper(diamonds,byCol="color",cols=c("av_price=mean(price)","m_depth=median(depth)"))
```

and get this output

```
  color cases av_price m_depth
1     D  6775 3169.954    61.8
2     E  9797 3076.752    61.8
3     F  9542 3724.886    61.8
4     G 11292 3999.136    61.8
5     H  8304 4486.669    61.9
6     I  5422 5091.875    61.9
7     J  2808 5323.818    62.0
```

but I don't know how to pass the cols argument of the outer function so it gets executed like an argument for the inner ddply function

I checked do.call but I don't know how to make use of it in this case.

By the way the usecase of this is a function which allows to collapse igraph ojects by a specific node attribute. I know that there is something similar already implemented in igraph but the way ddply handles this is just great!

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6584030/324364) help? I'm not entirely sure what summary you're trying to compute, since `length(x)` will return the number of columns of your data frame, but that link should help with some other issues you've run into.

Comment: I thought length(x) would return the number D's and E's and so on in the data.frame. Anyway thanks for the link but the idea behind all that is to create a function that is as flexible as ddply is. Thats why there is no specific summary I'am trying to compute. mean and median are just examples

Comment: Ok, that's the other question I had, whether you needed to pass different functions. The link _does_ address your incorrect use of `.()`, though, just so you know...I'll try to work on a more full answer.

Comment: Can you explain what functionality your proposed function would give you beyond using `ddply` itself? `ddply(diamonds, c("color"),summarise,cases = length(price),av_price = mean(price),m_depth = median(depth))`? Because the function you are describing basically _is_ `ddply`.

Comment: yes thats right :). Thats why I could it just ddply_wrapper :). i would like to use this not for a data.frame but for igraph objects=networks. Eg. a Network of Twitterusers and I would like to aggregate all users of a certain location to one node. I would then for example sum up all the nodes indegrees or calculate the average degree or something like that. the workflow is the convert the network into edge and nodes dataframe, ddply it and then build a new network out of it. thanks for your pacience :)

Comment: This is super easy with igraph. However, I have no idea what ddply's role is here. You can convert the network to a data frame and back with `get.data.frame()` and `graph.data.frame()` if that is what you are asking.

Comment: Hi Gabor. no that´s not the question, thats just the way how I would do it. What I would like to create is something like contract.vertices() but with the whole functionality of ddply for vertex.attr.comb.